# SIM900 not getting powered on

Tags: troubleshooting, sim900

I have a circuit where I am using a `SIM900` GSM/GPRS module. As per the datasheet it needs `3.4 V - 4.8 V` and upto 2 A of current. I am using `LM2576`. The input to the regulator is 12 V & 4.2 A and output (which is going to SIM900) is `4.175 V`. I have connected leds for `NETLIGHT` and `STATUS LIGHT`. I have connected a switch between `PWRKEY` and GND to start the SIM900. Following is the schematic of regulator:

[image]

SIM900:

[image]

The problem I am facing is as soon as I press the switch S1 to turn on the SIM900, its netlight led starts blinking and status light led is always off. What does this means? Is the module faulty? How can I debug it?

[Datasheet](https://www.amuroboclub.in/downloads/ebooks/GSM_MANUAL_SIM900_Hardware%20Design_V2.00.pdf)

Comment: Did you tried to use the debug port?

Comment: Is it a brand new modul or was it previously used? As @Adam suggested try to send a simple command to it and see if it answers. If the netlight is blinking then the module should be working on some level. Also you have missed to connect one GND pin, number 29.

Comment: @BenceKaulics Thanks for pointing out that 29 GND pin. Is it possible that the module is not turning on due to this unconnected GND pin.?

Comment: @BenceKaulics I connected the pin 29 to GND and tried but still the problem is same. I would also like to add that net light blinks whenever switch is pressed but as soon as I release the switch, it stops.

Comment: Press the switch, and measure the voltages on the board to see if it really has the required supply voltage.

Comment: @BenceKaulics Yes I measured the voltage at the VBAT pins. The voltage remains the same when I press the switch. It is `4.176v` and when I press the switch it becomes `4.156-4.165v`. I don't think there is any voltage problem in it.

Comment: After powering up the module do you receive a weird characters?if yes you must send some 'A' character for synchronous baud-rate between MCU and module

Comment: @MHD Thank you but the problem has now been resolved. I changed the inductor and used a 330uH inductor. I guess inductor was blocking the current needed by the SIM900.

Comment: Then please edit your question and add you approach to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the document "SIM900 hardware design:"

[image]

Seems that you might be up and running!

Time to connect the serial port...

If all else fails, some users report [reflashing the firmware worked.](http://www.geekonfire.com/wiki/index.php?title=GPRS_Shield%EF%BC%88SIM900%EF%BC%89_Firmware_Update)

Comment: Yes, but according to Figure 11. the Status pin should be logic high after power on. But its not for the OP.

Comment: Yes, as soon as I press the switch to make PWRKEY low, status led should be high but its not, which means the SIM900 is not ON. Instead the netlight starts blinking at very fast rate and keeps on blinking.

Comment: @S_Andrew check the added firmware reflash reference.  I assume that you've carefully checked the supply voltage to always remain within the specified range

Comment: Also, please add the timing of the led flashes to your question.

Comment: @neonzeon net led is blinking twice a second.

Comment: I assume that you've carefully checked the supply voltage to always remain within the specified range. The SIM900 turns itself off if the supply is above or below the limits.

Comment: Yes supply voltage is always stable. I am giving it 4.176 and it is stable. There is no voltage issue.

Comment: Several references say the Vrtc pin should not be left open.  Most designs (and their hardware design reference) suggest a 4.7uF ceramic capacitor.